# Is double-construction undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, object, c++11, constructor, lifetime

In our codebase, a pool of memory chunks is used and upon 'allocation' the object gets constructed using a "placement new". I'm missing the destructor call though, finding it odd to allow "double construction", and wonder if it is undefined behaviour to call the constructor another time on the same object.

In C++11 3.8.4 [basic.life] it reads

> A program may end the lifetime of any object by reusing the storage which the object occupies or by
> explicitly calling the destructor for an object of a class type with a non-trivial destructor. For an object
> of a class type with a non-trivial destructor, the program is not required to call the destructor explicitly
> before the storage which the object occupies is reused or released; however, if there is no explicit call to
> the destructor or if a delete-expression (5.3.5) is not used to release the storage, the destructor shall not be
> implicitly called and any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor has undefined
> behavior.

Does this mean that missing out the destructor call is actually ok, as long as we talk about types which have destructors without side-effects?

Edit: Context is: embedded SW without heap, own container implementations doing placement-new on c-array-elements or byte-arrays.

Comment: If you use placement-new to construct your objects, then you're actually constructing *different* objects even if they happen to re-use the same memory.

Comment: "Does this mean that missing out the destructor call is actually ok, as long as we talk about types which have destructors without side-effects?" Yes. But usually there is no point in declaring destructor which doesn't have side-effects. So, if you have user-defined destructors, then most probably they have side-effects and you need to call them. Also, note that side-effect can be buried in hierarchy very deeply, and be not obvious just from declarations of top objects.

Comment: You should always call the destructor of the first created object (or somehow make it fail to compile if it not the case) as during maintenance, one could add a destructor and don't know that some code assume the class does not have a destructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can double construct without UB.  The new object is a completely different one, and following pointers/references to the old one is UB.

It is really easy to trip over UB when doing placement new, let alone when double constructing.

Not calling a destructor just means the object is not cleaned up.  If the destructor is trivial, this is not going to have much risk.  Constructing an object over another object end an objects lifetime, as does calling the destructor.

If the object is in automatic storage with the proper type, constructing a different object over it and exiting the scope (causing the no longer existing original object to be destroyed) is usually UB (you can avoid UB here with a trivial destructor of the original object; this is why byte-buffers can have placement new done in them).

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64768155/2261538) already answers the question well.

Although, I would add that using **placement new** in production code is usually a bad practice, error prone and/or a mistake. Many excellent alternatives exist (including some libraries). So you should look to simpler alternatives (could be as simpel as using a `std::vector` instead - calling `reserve()` if absolutely needed!) - also sometimes the use and introduction of placement new in codebase in the first place is oftentime misguided, legacy or sometimes a case of premature optimization.

Albeit it's hard to give concrete advice - one method could be just remove placement new or replace it with some kind of standard container - and then check if any problems arises (usually performance).

**In my experience just removing the use of placement new in legacy code leads to no issues since the performance problem that it (maybe) used to fix has become largely obsolete by a wide range of 'system' optimizations (from the c++ level down to the hardward level).**

Comment: Granted, but there is no heap, I added context to the question.

Comment: @Borph I do not have much experience with "embedded c++", although I would still try to avoid "placement new" due to its error-prone-ness. std::array<T, MAX_AVAIL> or std::array<std::variant<...>, MAX_AVAIL> could be try'ed (you do not give the actual use case so its hard to be more concrete) - creating a custom allocator to use with standard containers MAYBE an option - but also an advanced concept. You do NOT need to use placement new in order to overwrite objects. Good luck.